# Unknown notifications

Tags: macos, notifications

I'm receiving time to time the notifications as shown on this screenshot.

[image]

The notifications are on the top right of my screen.

I can't understand the origin of these notifications thus I don't know to disable them.

What are they and how to disable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving push notifications from specific websites. Here's how to block them in Chrome, from [Google's support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?hl=en).

> **Allow or block notifications from all sites**
>
> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. In the upper right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu.
> 3. Click Settings > Show advanced settings.
> 4. In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.
> 5. In the dialog that appears, go to "Notifications" and choose one of the following:
>
>    - Allow all sites to show notifications: You’ll automatically see notifications from all websites.
>    - Ask when a site wants to show notifications: You’ll get an alert from Chrome whenever a site wants to show you notifications. This is the default setting.
>    - Do not allow any site to show notifications: You won’t see any notifications from websites.
>    - You can also block any sites, apps, and extensions that already have permission to send you notifications. Just click Manage exceptions.
>
> **Turn off notifications from some sites**
>
> 1. At the top of your screen in the menu bar, click the notification icon [which looks like a bell].
> 2. Click the gear icon.
> 3. Uncheck any website, extension or app you don’t want to receive notifications from.